# How to modify the fresh loaded/rendered content present in a <turbo-frame> element?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, stimulusjs

I've successfully implemented a search form (i.e. a text input field) that changes the [`src`](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/frames#html-attributes) attribute value of a [`<turbo-frame>`](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/frames) element (which one automatically fetches and renders data immediately after the change). The search result rendered in the `<turbo-frame>` is a `<ul><li>` list.

Now, I want to add a custom attribute (i.e. [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)) to the `<li>` list elements each time after the search result is loaded/rendered.

I tried to use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (on Stimulus controller, document and window with [Turbo events](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events) and non-Turbo events), the built-in Stimulus function [afterLoad](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers#trigger-behaviour-when-a-controller-is-registered) and some other weird things (e.g. [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)) without success.

How to modify the content present in the `<turbo-frame>` after it is freshly loaded/rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set `src` yourself, just add `turbo_frame: "name"` to the form and submit it.

```bash
bin/rails g scaffold Item name
bin/rails db:migrate
bin/rails g stimulus search
```

```rb
# app/controllers/items_controller.rb

def index
  @items = if params[:search].present?
    Item.where(Item.arel_table[:name].matches("%#{params[:search]}%"))
  else
    Item.all
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/views/items/index.html.erb

<%= tag.div data: {controller: "search"} do %>

  <%= form_with url: :items, method: :get,
    data: {search_target: "form", turbo_frame: :items} do |f| %>
    <%# NOTE: target the frame    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         %>

    <%= f.search_field :search, placeholder: "search...",
      data: {action: "search#autoSearch"} %>
  <% end %>

  <%= turbo_frame_tag :items, target: :_top,
    data: {search_target: "results", turbo_action: :advance} do %>
    <%# NOTE: to update url as well  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     %>

    <%= render @items %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/search_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

// Connects to data-controller="search"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["form", "results", "item"];

  connect() {
    this.resultsTarget.addEventListener("turbo:frame-render", this.resultsHandler);
  }

  resultsHandler(event) {
    event.target.querySelectorAll("li").forEach((li) => { 
      li.setAttribute("loaded", true); // <li loaded="true"></li>
    });
  }

  autoSearch() {
    // don't search on every keystroke
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.formTarget.requestSubmit(), 500);
  }

  // NOTE: you can also add a target and use target callbacks
  // <li data-search-target="item"> </li>
  itemTargetConnected(element) {
    // to skip initial page load
    if (this.resultsTarget.src) {
      element.setAttribute("loaded", true);
    }
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.resultsTarget.removeEventListener("turbo:frame-render", this.resultsHandler);
  }
}
```

*https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/targets#connected-and-disconnected-callbacks*

---

Instead of adding event listeners inside the controller, you can do it with `data-action`:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag :items, target: :_top,
  data: {
    turbo_action: :advance,
    action: "turbo:frame-render->search#resultsHandler"
  } do %>

  <%= render @items %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Even if possible in HTML5, in order to keep things simple, I don't want to have a nested form (FYI I'm using the search field nested into a form). However, `turbo:frame-render` doesn't get called (BTW `turbo:before-fetch-response` does). That's one of the reasons why I opened the question (there're other questions on the web about this). Actually, if this can be the problem (but I think it's not), the response to the search fetch request is a `<turbo-stream action="update" target="search_turbo_frame_id"><template><ul><li>...</template></turbo-stream>` which properly loads/renders the content.

Comment: By using the `turbo:before-fetch-response` and `turbo:before-fetch-request` Turbo events (note: the only ones that fire) the `event.target.querySelectorAll("li")` returns an empty NodeList with length 0 i.e. `<li>` elements are not recognized.

Comment: @Backo you'll have to show your code so i can see what you're doing. you said one thing in your question and completely different thing in your comment, i don't see what turbo-frame has to do with any of it now. `turbo:before-stream-render` should work where you have access to stream and can change it as needed.